# Create Site Page via REST API

Tags: sharepoint-online, javascript, rest, sharepoint-rest-api

I would like to create a Site Page via REST API with my own Title and Content.
So far I tried to send a POST request but got an error:

> To add an item to a document library, use SPFileCollection.Add()

POST: `<url>/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('Site Pages')/Items`

Body:

```
{
  "__metadata": {
    "type": "SP.Data.SitePagesItem"
  },
  "Title": "It's working?"
}
```

From what I understand - first I need to create a Site Page (a file) in SharePoint and then modify it via REST.
However, my requirement is to create the entire entry via REST only.

How can this be done?

Answer (score 1):

[This](https://www.codesharepoint.com/rest-api/create-wiki-page-in-sharepoint-using-rest-api) is a great article explaining how to do this. Essentially, it creates a new `.aspx` file in the Site Pages library. Here is the code they use (called from a page on the target web):

```
function CreateWikiPage() {

// Get Server relative url of Web(site)
var WebServerRelativeUrl = _spPageContextInfo.webServerRelativeUrl;

// Provide Internal name of the library here
var DocuentLibraryInternalName = "SitePages";

// Provide name of the wiki page to be created
var NewPageName = "NewRESTWikipage.aspx";

// Form relative url of the new page. This will be used in function below
var NewFileUrl = WebServerRelativeUrl + "/" + DocuentLibraryInternalName + "/" + NewPageName;

$.ajax({

    // "templateFileType" values in below method
    // StandardPage. The value = 0.
    // WikiPage. The value = 1.
    // FormPage. The value = 2.

    url: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('" + WebServerRelativeUrl + "/" + DocuentLibraryInternalName + "')/Files/AddTemplateFile(urlOfFile='" + NewFileUrl + "',templateFileType=1)",
    method: "POST",
    headers: {
        "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
        "content-type": "application/json;odata=verbose",
        "X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val()
    },
    success: function (data, status, xhr) {
        console.log("Success");
    },
    error: function (xhr, status, error) {
        console.log("Failed");
    }
});
}
```

Comment: The given code creates a "Wiki Page" instead of "Site Page". From what I understand, this "Wiki Page" is an old version of SharePoint entries. I need to create a "new" version of this entry - so "Site Page" instead of "Wiki Page". Nevertheless, thanks for the Pro Tip :)

Comment: I think, it's just very simple - need to use templateFileType=3 instead of 1, as it's ClientSidePage https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.sharepoint.client.templatefiletype?view=sharepoint-csom

Answer (score 0):

1. Create the Template of a "modern entries" in SharePoint. Follow [this](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/page-templates-in-sharepoint-faa92408-0c84-4e3d-8460-3c28065e7873) guide to do that.
2. Create a new Site Page via REST API using that saved template. Just copy it from Template folder to Root folder of that subpage:
   `/_api/Web/GetFileByServerRelativeUrl('<source_url>')/CopyTo(strnewurl='<target_url>',bOverwrite=false)`
3. Edit that newly created Site Page as you wish (eg. via REST API).

Source and Target URLs:

`source_url` - `/sites/<your_site>/SitePages/Templates/Your-Template.aspx`

`target_url` - `/sites/<your_site>/SitePages/New-Modern-Page.aspx`